# Syntax error in MS Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm getting a syntax error ("Missing Operator") in my MS Access record source.
SQL Server 2012 executes it without a problem but when I let Access 2016 execute it, I get this error. I expect that Access has different case statement requirements but I'm not sure.

```
SELECT 
    r.Rubrieknaam, 
    CASE 
       WHEN (SELECT count(Voorwerpnummer) 
             FROM VoorwerpInRubriek 
             WHERE rubrieknummer = r.Rubrieknummer) IS NULL 
          THEN 0
          ELSE (SELECT count(Voorwerpnummer) 
                FROM VoorwerpInRubriek 
                WHERE rubrieknummer = r.Rubrieknummer) 
    END AS [nInRubriek], 
    CASE
       WHEN (SELECT Count(*) 
             FROM Rubriek 
             WHERE HoofdrubriekNr = r.rubriekNummer) IS NULL 
          THEN 0
          ELSE (SELECT Count(*) 
             FROM Rubriek 
             WHERE HoofdrubriekNr = r.rubriekNummer) 
    END AS [nSubrubrieken], 
    CASE 
       WHEN (SELECT Rubrieknaam 
             FROM Rubriek 
             WHERE Rubrieknummer = r.hoofdrubrieknr) IS NULL 
          THEN 'N.V.T.'
          ELSE (SELECT Rubrieknaam 
             FROM Rubriek 
             WHERE Rubrieknummer = r.hoofdrubrieknr)
    END AS [Hoofdrubrieknaam]
FROM 
    Rubriek r;
```

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MS Access does not support `case`.  In addition, `count()` in a subquery doesn't return `NULL`, it returns `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `CASE-ELSE` is T-SQL.

Use `IIf(expression, true expression, false expression)` in Access SQL.

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem. It however massively affected the query performance so I decided to not use it in my form. This was the answer for my question I was looking for though.

Answer (score 1):

The query should look like:

```
SELECT r.Rubrieknaam, 
       (SELECT count(Voorwerpnummer) FROM VoorwerpInRubriek WHERE rubrieknummer = r.Rubrieknummer
       ) AS [nInRubriek], 
       (SELECT Count(*) FROM Rubriek WHERE HoofdrubriekNr = r.rubriekNummer
       )  AS [nSubrubrieken], 
       NZ(Rubrieknaam, "N.V.T.") AS [Hoofdrubrieknaam]
FROM Rubriek r;
```

Conditional logic isn't even needed.

Comment: Yes I found that out and returned my query to the original query(which is like the one you send.) I got an error about invalid numeric values making me think that the 0 or NULL created a problem. The problem however was that the connection to my database was giving errors and returning invalid values. Thanks for the help.